# Start a new chapter without heading

Tags: sectioning, chapters

In the appendix of my thesis (using `scrreprt`) I want to start a new chapter containing a lot of large figures. For formating reasons I don't want the automatic heading, created when using `\chapter{bla}`. 
However I do want the chapter to appear in the TOC and also I want the page header to show the chapter correctly.

So my question is, is there a way to start a new chapter without the automatic heading? I don't want all chapters to be without heading, only this one.

Comment: Does the following meet your need? \chapter[My Contents Title]{}

Comment: Unfortunaly not, because number of the chapter is still printed, e.g. "A." in my case. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The chapter head is typeset by `\@makechapterhead`, which is a macro with one argument, while the TOC entry and the heading are direct responsibiity of `\@chapter` and independent of `\@makechapterhead`. If we temporarily redefine it to simply gobble its argument, we're done.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular}

Text

\unchapter{No chapter head}

Text\newpage
text: check the heading

\chapter{This is regular again}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You golden god saving us from thesis formatting hell bless you

Comment: I also need to have a chapter entered into the toc without the heading printed on the Chapter starting page.  But I use `\chapter*{}`... so as to not print the number of the chapter beside the titles in the toc ... and then I use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont\textit{bla}}`.    This solution causes the chapter to have a number printed in the toc ... Is there a way to modify this solution to suit my needs ?

Comment: @RichWalt `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{text}` will not add chapter numbers.

Comment: @egreg ... and I do not want a chapter number either.  :-)  Howerver, this solution is adding one.  I'm trying to modify it so as to NOT have a chapter number.

Comment: @RichWalt Please ask a new question with the details of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks ... will do.    Check here:  <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636746/enter-an-unnumbered-chapter-entry-into-the-toc-but-do-not-print-a-chapter-title>

Answer (score 2):

An old exchange...

but I have a great solution so I give it.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
     \markboth{#1}{}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

And, of course, replace `\chapter` by `\mychapter` in your latex file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you sure this is a great solution? You will still create the heading with this (`\chapter*`) which is not what the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice combination of both:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makeschapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter*{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \markboth{#1}{}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Makes the header disappear and a contentsline in the table of contents without a number.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you saw the -1 for the second answer and the comment below?