# How to let Bibliography appear in one page

Tags: bibliographies

After I compile my text, it shows like this:
[image]

I want to combine the text of Bibliography to the first page. How to do that?
My code is:

```
\chapter{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Wellner, P. (1993). Interacting with paper on the DigitalDesk. Communications of the ACM, 36(7), pp.87-96.
```

I thinks the problem is \chapter{Bibliography} and \begin{thebibliography}{} write the title of Bibliography twice..
Hope someone can help..

Comment: It is indeed as you say. Just remove `\chapter` and only use `\begin{thebibliography}{}`.

Comment: By the way, there are several other things. Why are you typesetting the bibliography by hand? It would be much wiser to use LaTeX's ability to handle bibliographies automatically, preferably via BibLaTeX. Another thing is, why is the bibliography an appendix, it should normally be the last chapter/section/whatever of the main text. And just for the record, it is normally much better to post a full working minimal example if you want to have help, especially for more complex problems than this.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf But if I remove \chapter.. I will lose Appendix B.. I need that title to clarify my page..

Comment: Again, why should a bibliography be an appendix. Appendices contain _additional_ data, which the bibliography clearly is not!

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Just want to remain the Appendix B....Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You may start a new chapter without printing the actual chapter title, this may work. Look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199972/start-a-new-chapter-without-heading). I cannot test that, because **you do not provide a minimal example** with which that would be possible, and it is **your job** to put that together. And just for the record, once again, _a bibliography absolutely does not belong in an appendix_!

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf it's perfectly possible that the OP has to follow a style that says otherwise.  It's also perfectly possible for a bibliography of sorts to form an appendix (further reading, for example -- I have textbooks that do this)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Comment: The bit of code you showed us indicates you are not using `biblatex`, in order to avoid confusion I have removed the tag.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use.

Comment: @Mico The document class is \documentclass[
11pt, 
english,
singlespacing, 
headsepline, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following in the preamble of your document (i.e., between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`):

```
\makeatletter
\let\thebibliography@ori\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
   \renewcommand{\@schapter}[1]{\@chapter[##1]{##1}}\thebibliography@ori{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: But in the table of Content, this solution will only show 'B', not the 'B Bibliography'

Comment: @Hanslen Chen Corrected.  You'll now see "B Bibliography".