# Start a new starchapter without heading

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm trying to make a `\chapter*` without heading, just like this solution:

[Start a new chapter without heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199972/start-a-new-chapter-without-heading][1])

So, how I start a `\chapter*` without any headings? And like before, not all the chapters, just this one

Comment: Why not just `\clearpage`? Are you interested in a vertical gap from the top of the page?

Comment: because I need to include this page in ToC. I'm not sure that's how I should do it, but my idea was to make this `\chapter*` with no heading, and without messing up with the chapter number from the real text too, that's why the star version

Comment: So you can do `\clearpage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{stuff}` if you want the formatting of `\chapter` (without the number)...

Comment: I didn't follow. `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{stuff}` adds the chapter 'stuff' in ToC, right? But I need to add a `\chapter*` . It's the same command for adding in ToC, but then I get the headings from the starchapters definitions.