# Enter an UNNUMBERED chapter entry into the TOC; But do not print a chapter title (header) for a single chapter's starting page

Tags: table-of-contents

I tried the solution given in [Start a new chapter without heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199972/start-a-new-chapter-without-heading) Which temporally causes `@makechapterhead` to simply gobble it's text argument.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\unchapter{test chapter}
```

However, this prints a NUMBERED  "test chapter" in the TOC.

In my book document ... I use `\chapter*{test chapter}` (which is unnumbered, but is also not printed in toc either) ... in combination with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{test chapter}` ... which does make an entry in the TOC for the current chapter.

Is there anyway to modify the solution given above for my particular case?  I want an unnumbered entry in the toc, and also no title header on the chapter's starting page - for a single chapter only.

I tried to modify the above solution for my case as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter*{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\unchapter{test chapter}
```

But this still causes a chapter title header to be printed on the chapter's starting page.

**Recap:**. The first solution works (as far as not printing a title on the chapter's starting page - which is what I want) ... but makes the toc entry as a numbered chapter (whereas I need an unnumbered entry for the chapter in the toc).

My attempt to modify the first solution, given as the second solution ... still makes a chapter's start contain a printed header.

Comment: This is not a very elegant solution ... but it does work:    `\chapter*{\phantom{Chapter Title Here}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter Title Here} 

\vspace{-2in}   text of your page`   still, I am hoping for a more elegant solution than this hack.

Comment: What's the problem with `\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{text}`?

Comment: I could try that ... but first, let me ask, I have the flag set to FALSE for start chapters on right ... will this mess that up ?  I'm trying to reproduce a book exactly, (page for page) and it has some of it's TOC entries starting on the left hand side ... it only uses a level-0 class for toc entries.

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` will not skip to an odd-numbered page if the `openany` option is in force, which is the default for `report`, but has to be given to `book`.

Comment: I'll give it a try ... but I was referring to: `\csname @openrightfalse\endcsname  %forces chapter to start on left page if next page is on left`

Comment: Why doing things the complicated way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134710/discussion-between-richwalt-and-egreg).

Comment: so ... the \cleardoublepage method you're suggesting does not work.  (a) in introduces new blank pages in the document, and (b) the LINKING for toc sends you back to the previous chapter, not the current chapter after the \cleardoublepage that I need.  Just posting this for others who may visit this thread.

Comment: Your question has so few detals… Did you mention `hyperref`? Did you try the `openany` option? Did you try `\clearpage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is already in [start chapter with no headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624410/161015)

(1) Second chapter starts without heading

(2) An entry is added to the ToC

(3) Links in ToC works fine.

[image: b]

Link of `Test unchapter` remits to page 5, the starting of the chapter without headings.

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}   

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% only dummy text

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{% FROM https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624410/161015
    \begingroup
    \let\@makeschapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{}
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
1. \kant[1]

\unchapter{Test unchapter}
2. \kant[2]

\chapter{Two}

3. \kant[3]     
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works ! Perfect.    Thanks.